# Scalar function (NON table-valued function) in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, remote-server, linked-server

I use PostgreSQL as linked server from SQL Server. Now, I need to call PostgreSQL function which returns ONLY one integer (scalar), but SQL Server doesn't allow remote table-valued functions and says that this query is a table-valued function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getpointinfo(
    IN lng double precision,
    IN lat double precision)
RETURNS integer
AS
$$
DECLARE result integer;
begin
result:= case when cwt.k like 'maxspeed' then cast(cwt.v as integer)
            else getmaxspeed(s.highway)
            end maxspeed
from snapPointToLine(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($1, $2), 4326)) s
   join current_way_tags cwt
   on s.id = cwt.way_id
where cwt.k in ('maxspeed', 'highway')
order by cwt.k desc
limit 1;
return result;
end
$$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

How can I modify this PostgreSQL query to return scalar value, or to be able to use it as four part name function from SQL Server like

```
select objectid, s.data_source
from testData
outer apply
(
select maxspeed from MB24DB.MobTrack24DB.[public].getpointinfo(X, Y)
) s
```

`openquery` is not an option.

Comment: The posted function has an obvious syntax error.

Comment: A scalar function should not be used in the `from` clause. And because you do so, I guess SQL Server assumes it is a table-valued function. And because it's a scalar function, I don't see the need to use `cross apply` in the first place. Just put `MB24DB.MobTrack24DB.[public].getpointinfo(X, Y)` into the `select` list (assuming your table `testdata` has the two column x and y)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Error thrown:
Remote function reference 'MB24DB.MobTrack24DB.public.getpointinfo' is not allowed, and the column name 'MB24DB' could not be found or is ambiguous.
testData contains X and Y columns.

Comment: then try `outer apply (select MB24DB.MobTrack24DB.[public].getpointinfo(X, Y)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Same error.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Even with these 'improvements' it doesn't work. Syntax is good now.

Comment: BTW you can simplify your function a bit using `sql` language instead of `plpgsql` like `create function ... returns integer as $$ select ... $$ language sql;`

Comment: Why is openquery not an option?

Comment: @Ben I have table in SQL Server with lat/lng and I need to get speed limit for each row. I my postgresql function accepts lat/lng as argument, I can not dynamically create openquery string and use it in select.

Comment: "I can not dynamically create openquery string and use it in select" yes you can. You can write a SQL Server scalar valued function, which internally uses OPENQUERY, on a dynamic string, to exec the function on the remote server, and return the results. Then use the SQL Server function in your SELECT.

Comment: In reality you would probably be better to copy all of the data to SQL server and do it all locally, however.

Comment: @Ben How to execute that dynamic openquery? I executed using sp_executesql which cann't go into function.

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar things before. There are three basic tricks you can use.

**First Trick: `xp_cmdshell`**

You can call `xp_cmdshell` from a UDF. So the trick is to have `xp_cmdshell` call `sqlcmd` (or `osql`) to place the results into a table, then you can select them out of the table. You can key the results with your own SPID.

```
use tempdb
go
create table Results(
scope varchar(20) primary key,
result integer
)
go
    create function dbo.test(@x integer, @y integer)
returns integer
as
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    declare @scope varchar(20) set @scope = 'dbo.test@' + cast(@@spid as varchar(36))
    set @sql = 'delete tempdb.dbo.Results where spid = '+@scope + '; '
    set @sql = 'insert tempdb.dbo.Results select '+@scope+', '+cast(@x as nvarchar(max))+' * '+cast(@y as nvarchar(max))+' as r; '
    declare @cmd varchar(max)
    set @cmd = 'sqlcmd -E -Q "' + @sql +'"'
    set @cmd = 'CMD /S /C "' + @cmd + ' 2>&1"'
    exec xp_cmdshell @sql, NO_OUTPUT
    declare @r integer 
    select @r = result from tempdb.dbo.results where scope = @scope
    return @r
end
```

Alternatively, you can also do `insert/exec` **to a table variable** with `xp_cmdshell` from a UDF, then parse the output data.

```
declare @CMD nvarchar(max)
set @CMD = 'echo.Hello World!'
set @CMD = 'CMD /S/C "' + @cmd + ' 2>&1"'
declare @results table (ix int identity primary key, txt nvarchar(max)
declare @exitcode int
insert @results(txt)
exec @exitcode = xp_cmdshell @commandtext

-- You now have the results of your command.
```

**Second Trick: `sp_OACreate`**

You can use sp_OACreate from a UDF. This means that you can create an ADO connection back to your own database and do any arbitrary actions you wish, including placing the results in a table for reference. `sp_OACreate` is a pain to use however, so I will leave you to the documentation for the details.

**Third Trick: SQLCLR**

You can work around all these restrictions using a CLR function, which can connect directly to your postgres database and do whatever you want.

Comment: Ben, as I said in comments, it throws an error:  Remote function reference 'MB24DB.MobTrack24DB.public.getpointinfo' is not allowed, and the column name 'MB24DB' could not be found or is ambiguous.

I already tried all of suggested.